# Event Listener for button click in another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, addeventlistener, mapbox-gl-js

I am using MapBox in React, where it has a navbar parent. I have a button in the navbar component that collapses the navbar by changing it's class, where I also want to execute the code below in the map component when this button is pressed.

```
map.easeTo({
padding: {left:300},
duration: 1000
});
```

I feel like the function addEventListener() can acomplish this, however the navbar and the map are separate components in two different js files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: yep is possible to create a custom event for achieving what your want, but I recommend you try using a context or a global state like redux to track your app state.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them both in a parent component that keeps the navbar state, then pass the state and the state setter to both children. You can also use context, but on that level of nesting it is kind of an overkill

Example:

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return {
    <>
      <Navbar isExpanded={isExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded} />
      <Map isExpanded={isExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded} />
    </>
  }
}
```